# How to execute stripe payment html call from asp.net child form

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to initiate the following call to the Stripe script which requests the page /Members/Charge.aspx via POST in a sample HTML form.  I need to do this on an existing aspx child page that uses a Site.Master page (so it is between asp content place holders so i can't use the form method="post" etc.

How can i do the following but from an existing ASP content child page?

This is the sample code from Stripe that works:

```html
<form action="/Members/Charge" method="post">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<%= stripePublishableKey %>"
        data-amount="500"
        data-name="Stripe.com"
        data-description="Sample Charge"
        data-image="/images/home.jpg"
        data-locale="auto"
        data-zip-code="true">
    </script>
</form>
```

I need it to be something like this:

```
            <div class="col">
                <h5 style="font-weight:bold">Payment Method</h5>
                <script
                    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                    data-key="<%= stripePublishableKey %>"
                    data-amount="500"
                    data-name="Stripe.com"
                    data-description="Sample Charge"
                    data-image="/images/home.jpg"
                    data-locale="auto"
                    data-zip-code="true">
                </script>
            </div>
```

In my aspx child page between the asp:Content tags, but then how do I redirect to my charge page since I can't use the line:?

```
<form action="/Members/Charge" method="post">
```

Which then redirects to the 'charge' page which is the transaction successful page with the following code on page_load which actually submits the transaction

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Form["stripeToken"] != null)
            {

                var customers = new CustomerService();
                var charges = new ChargeService();

                var customer = customers.Create(new CustomerCreateOptions
                {
                    Email = Request.Form["stripeEmail"],
                    SourceToken = Request.Form["stripeToken"]
                });

                var charge = charges.Create(new ChargeCreateOptions
                {
                    Amount = 500,
                    Description = "Sample Charge",
                    Currency = "usd",
                    CustomerId = customer.Id
                });

                Console.WriteLine(charge);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I assume you do need to use the form tag to make it work, why not use it with empty action so that it would post to the current URL, i.e. current page?

Comment: It then posts to the 'charge' page - i edited my question to include it, thank you

Comment: The way you said you can't use the line for form tag is confusing to me. It looks like you're already adding a h5 tag before the script so you can just wrap the whole thing in the form tag. In your comment you mentioned that it will post to the charge page if you use the form tag without the action URL, so isn't that what you were trying to achieve? It seems to me that you're not facing any problem, or you're not explaining the actual problem

Comment: I can't do that since i'm on an asp.net child page between the asp:content tags so you can't place form tags within those

Comment: Okay I see it now, it's impossible to use two forms so one possible solution is to wrap the child in an iframe

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I suppose i'm bothered by this issue because i'm curious as to how these payment systems or how to handle that logic in general of calling some javascript of an API and landing on a POST page based on some results of the user input of the js interface requested.  Seems like an impass.  You do bring up a good point though, I suppose I will just call an interim "confirm order" page of sorts designed with just the simple HTML form at the beginning of my post.  Still want to solve though..thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had to call an interim "confirm order" page of sorts designed with just the simple HTML form at the beginning of my post